# Static assertion for atomic read/write of value

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

Is there a way to check if the reading/writing (load/store) of a value is atomic? I have specialized versions of concurrent containers than can only work with such values and I would like to add a static assert to prevent accidental misuse.

For all the fundamental types on x86_64 this is true, but it may not be true for all platforms, or all long data types.  Also, it is possible that small structures and unions will also be assigned with an atomic operation (since they'd just be compiled to use the same-size fundamental copy operation).

Comment: You're right to be worried, [Sparc cannot write 32 bits atomically](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-13.html). But I have trouble envisioning assertions that could prove the correctness of atomic writes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++0x draft has a section with macros in the <atomic> header, which indicates that there is no easy and portable way to check this otherwise.

> **29.4 Lock-free property** [atomics.lockfree]

```
#define ATOMIC_CHAR_LOCK_FREE implementation-defined 
#define ATOMIC_CHAR16_T_LOCK_FREE implementation-defined 
#define ATOMIC_CHAR32_T_LOCK_FREE implementation-defined 
#define ATOMIC_WCHAR_T_LOCK_FREE implementation-defined 
#define ATOMIC_SHORT_LOCK_FREE implementation-defined 
#define ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE implementation-defined 
#define ATOMIC_LONG_LOCK_FREE implementation-defined 
#define ATOMIC_LLONG_LOCK_FREE implementation-defined
```

The macros indicates the types where std::atomic<type> can be implemented without a lock, which means that they are atomic in themselves.

Comment: Hmm, this is good information. I might be able to build a series of static asserts out of it (it wouldn't be generic however).

Comment: I guess technically this says the "atomic" operations as defined by the standard are lock free. That may actually be more restrictive than what I want. But it's something at least.

Answer (score 0):

The only method you have is to dump the generated assembly of each function and refer to the processor vendor's notes for the instructions atomicity guarantees.